# Как лучше реализовать локализацию в php

Tags: php, локализация

```
class Text {
  const _MENU = 'Меню';
}
echo '<a href="/menu">'.Text::_MENU.'</a>'; // На выходе
```

или же

```
define("_MENU","Меню");
echo '<a href="/menu">'._MENU.'</a>'; // На выходе
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gettext.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Достаточно просто подключать разные шаблоны в зависимости от настроек, т.е. например все шаблоны хранятся в папке view
Например oписываем класс Localization который принимает значение языка, в папке view создаем папки типа ru, ua, en. Задача данного класса будет очень простой - подключать шаблоны из этих папок в зависимости от принятых параметров, если языка 2-3 нормальная практика, если же больше то естественно нужно использовать БД. Но опять таки тут нам поможет класс типа Localization. Просто тогда его задача будет в зависимости от принятых параметров отдавать в шаблоны данные на том или ином языке.

*PS:класс Localization лучше всего сделать singleton'ом*

Comment: На самом деле достаточно геморойный вариант. Вот представим что у нас есть 5 языков, соответственно у нас будет 5 копий темплейт.
И тут у нас возникает потребность что-то изменить в дизайне сайта. Как минимум нам потребуется делать 5 раз одно и тоже ...

Comment: на самом деле внимательно читать надо то что я пишу перед тем как изьяснять свои мысли<br>Я просто сомневаюсь в вашей адекватности и повторюсь:<b> если языка 2-3 нормальная практика, если же больше то естественно нужно использовать БД</b><br>
<small>Еще вопросы будут?</small>

Comment: Пусть даже 2-3. Это все равно много

Comment: ок, какие у вас варианты? Думаете легче реализовать намного проще реализовать локализацию использую БД? Вообщем не суть, у вас вообще был опыт реализации? Если нет то о чем мы вообще говорим, а если был, то ооочень интерестно как же хитромудро это было реализовано вами?

Comment: О чем вообще разговор ?
Если используется шаблонизатор и переводы внутри бд то при добавлении очередного языка не нужно создавать копию уже имеющихся шаблонов, а просто изменить настройки языка и все что нужно будет сделать - это перевести все нужные слова на нужный язык. При этом в сами шаблоны мы не лезем.
А при изменении дизайна сайта нам нужно будет править только одну копию шаблонов.

Answer (score 2):

Если системных фраз мало - второй способ. Причем, подключаемый из отдельного файла.
если много - лучше через БД: редактировать и управлять проще, хотя немного увеличивается время обработки.
В друпале, например, есть функция

```
t($str)
```

, которая ищет в БД английский вариант строки и возвращает его аналог на запрошенном языке(указанном в настройках). Если ничего не найдено или возник сбой соединения, возвращается оригинальная строка. Это позволяет пользоваться даже аварийным вариантом.

Comment: Язык будет использоваться только один. Системных фраз будет довольно много. То что подключаемый из отдельного файла это я в курсе. Интересует мнение и плюсы/минусы реализации.

Answer (score 2):

Я реализовал на сессиях. Все диалоги находятся в файлах ru.php и en.php и определены константами. И идет проверка в файле `undex.php`: `if ($_SESSION['lang']=='ru') {include_once'ru.php';} else {include_once'en.php';}`.
Статьи же хранятся в базе, в таблицах статей и новостей существуют поля `text_rus` и `text_eng`.

Answer (score 1):

Самый хороший способ что я видел - это использовать некоторую функцию/класс
во входящих параметрах будет текст и язык. Функция смотрит в своем кеше (который предварительно загружает из БД) нету ли такого перевода для данного текста на нужный язык, если есть - то возвращает его, если нету - то добавляет запись в таблицу с таким же переводом как и само переводимое слово.
А в базе вы уже переводите это слово как хотите. После перевода нужно сбрасывать кеш.

Answer (score 0):

Только вчера делал подобное себе...
Делаем форму, которая отсылает на 2 значение rus и eng.
Дальше php.

```
<?
//если пришел ответ ru создаем сессию $_SESSION['lang'] которая ровна ru
if($_POST['ru']){
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['ru'];
}
если пришел ответ en создаем сессию $_SESSION['lang'] которая ровна en
if($_POST['en']){
$_SESSION['lang'] = $_POST['en'];
}
if(!$_SESSION['lang']) { include("lang/ru.php"); }// сессия пустая - язык по умолчанию - русский
//ну тут всё понятно...
if($_SESSION['lang'] == russian) { include("lang/ru.php"); }
if($_SESSION['lang'] == english) { include("lang/en.php"); }
?>
<? echo $lang['find']; ?> //тестим
```

В файлах ru.php и en.php находиться массив `$lang`.

Если у вас несколько разбросанных страниц, то строки

```
if($_SESSION['lang'] == russian) { include("lang/ru.php"); }
if($_SESSION['lang'] == english) { include("lang/en.php"); }
```

надо вставлять на каждой странице В САМОМ НАЧАЛЕ.

Comment: Вопрос был не как подключить и что использовать - т.е. сесии или куки а именно в define или const. как подключить и прочее я в курсе)

Comment: Кстате еще раз добавлю комент. Как по мне - очень много кода, проще реализовать классом!

Comment: @Palmervan, я тоже за  *class Test*

PS: пожалуйста,по ходу дела можете как то
описывать это дело, просто мне стало интересно.
Какие проблемы возникают,как вы решили задачу и .т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал следующим образом.
**Перевод контента - в БД**, в соответствующих полях типа **product.name*_*ru** (или в **отдельной таблице** для локализации).
**Перевод UI - в отдельных файлах**, с названием, например `/view/themes/autumn_in_yellow/lang/ru.php` . Для каждого языка создаём свой файл. Содержимое файлов локализации примерно следующее:

```
$t['catalog.minicart.content.after_nbr'] = 
        $this->form_multi('товар', $data['cart_prod_count']). ' в корзине';
$t['catalog.minicart.content.before_nbr'] = 'У вас ';
$t['site.footer.contacts.title'] = 'Наши контакты:';
$t['site.rss_feed'] = 'Rss лента';
```

Структура папок/файлов, напр., может быть такой (описываю только view):

```
htdocs
 |- view
 |   |- classes
 |   |   |- translater
 |   |   |- ...
 |   |- themes
 |       |- autumn_in_yellow
 |       |   |- fonts
 |       |   |- images
 |       |   |- lang
 |       |   |   |- ru.php
 |       |   |   |- ua.php
 |       |   |   |- de.php
 |       |   |   |- es.php
 |       |   |   |- fr.php
 |       |   |- scripts
 |       |   |- catalog.phtml
 |       |   |- footer.phtml
 |       |   |- header.phtml
 |       |   |- index.phtml
 |       |   |- minicart.phtml
 |       |   |- static.phtml
 |       |   |- ...
 |       |- default
 |           |- fonts
 |           |- ...
 |- index.php
 |- ...
```

Файл шаблона, соответственно, может быть таким (`/view/themes/autumn_in_yellow/minicart.phtml`):

```
<div class="cart">
    <div class="title"><?=$t->tr('catalog.minicart.content.before_nbr'). " $cart_prod_count " .$t->tr('catalog.minicart.content.after_nbr')?></div>
    <div id="minicart_details"></div>
    <div class="more"><a href="/cart"><?=$t->tr('catalog.minicart.go_to_cart')?></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с shurik. На 100% невозможно знать сколько языков понадобится. Представляю, когда шаблонов 50 и добавляется новый язык сколько придется заниматься копипастом шаблонов. Альтернативой базе является просто массив в файле для каждого языка, где значение является переводом. Или yml файл или любая другая структура.
То, что советует AlexWindHope является последней буквой STUPID принципа и не соблюдает DRY подход.
Посмотрите как реализовано в symfony/Translation.

Answer (score 0):

Все-таки оставлю здесь ответ, несмотря на то, что он есть в комментарии (он там практически не виден). В достаточно больших проектах (а другие локализовать не вижу смысла) вместо "велосипедов" следует использовать надежное решение, проверенное временем - [gettext](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.gettext.php).

1. Есть встроенная поддержка php (по крайней мере модуль идет в стандартной поставке php и отключать его я бы не стал). Если модуль отключен, можно взять из Wordpress'а реализацию на php;
2. Есть достаточно удобный инструментарий для создания/редактирования файлов локализации;
3. Локализация на новый язык потребует минимального вмешательства в код php/